# Powershell ISE run Python script and passing variables

Tags: python, powershell, variables, environment

I would like to run my python script from Powershell ISE. How do I do that when I also want to pass parameters to the python script. Basicly I want the user to use the script and make little changes, without the neeed to change the actual python script.

This is how the 4 variables are currently written in python:

```
campaign = "ABC"
dir_xml = r'd:\path\xml'
dir_pictures = r'd:\path\pictures'
dir_output = r'd:\path\output'
```

I want those 4 variables written in powershell script. What needs to be changed in my python script and how do I pass the variables in powershell?

Also I would like to freeze my packages I have used in the script and copy those in a directory from a different computer. How can I make it possible that the user do not have to  install any packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Passing command line arguments from powershell script to a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38009185/1701026). For the other question "*freeze my packages*"? (See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Are you aiming for a docker container?

Comment: No that doesn't answer my question unfortunetly, I need to know what I need to change within my python script and how i write the powershell line. The link you posted only shows a powershell script, so I dont understand the link to python.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself, this is my current solution:

In powershell:

```
$campaign = "ABC"
$dir_xml = "d:\path\xml"
$dir_pictures = "d:\path\pictures"
$dir_output = "d:\path\output"

python path\file.py -c $campaign, -x $dir_xml, -p $dir_pictures, -o $dir_output
```

In python:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-c", "--campagne", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-x", "--xml", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-p", "--picture", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```